# Glossy reflecting only one object

Tags: compositing-nodes, shaders, tracking

### Glossy in camera tracking

I am having some fun with camera-tracking in Blender. 
That is my result so far: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8-GudfIzi0

My question is: how can I make this table reflect the ship?

Nodes are standard Blender's setup for motion tracking. 
There is a plane on Backround layer, receiveing the shadow. I tried adding glossy shader to the plane. But then plane is reflecting surroundings (light and skybox) which is breaking the effect.

Good solution for me would be if plane could reflect only the ship, and be transparent to all the other, but I don't know how to approach this.

Do you know any trick that could help me out?

Answer (score 0):

A while back, I found [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/YCL7MSFLA3o) on YouTube. Perhaps you can do something similar.

Another thing you could consider is taking a picture of the desk and mapping it onto your shadow-receiving plane. Then try adding glossiness again. This should provide a nicer rendition.